# Sheets("Sheet Name").select Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue when running a VBA macro in a .xlsm file in Excel 2013.
All instances of `Sheets("SheetName").Select` or `Sheets("SheetName").Activate` error when executed.

This is an example of one of the code samples that errors:

```
Sub Reset_Additional()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Additional").Select                 <-- Code breaks on this line

    Range("additionalcheckbox").Select
    Selection.Value = False
    Range("additional1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("additional2").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("additional3").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]"
    Range("additional4").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-18]"
    Range("additional5").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-18]"
    Range("additional6").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]"

    Sheets("Macro Rules").Select

    Range("B21").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[+1]" 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is the VB error that occurs:
[image: VB Error]

The macro is supposed to reset some fields across a few sheets in the workbook.  The macro was previously working before a team member worked on the file with an earlier version of Excel and since then this error has happened.  I haven't been able to find much through searching around on this specific situation.    Reverting to an old version would be my last resort due to time constraints.  Any way to fix this would be awesome.

Comment: Side Note: I recommend to read [VBA Best Practices - Avoid using Select](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate)

Comment: @Peh Thanks for the guide, will use this going forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use `.Selection`
You should use:

```
Sub Reset_Additional()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Additional")
        .Range("additionalcheckbox").Value = False
        .Range("additional1").ClearContents
        .Range("additional2").ClearContents
        .Range("additional3").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]"
        .Range("additional4").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-18]"
        .Range("additional5").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-18]"
        .Range("additional6").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]"
    End With

    With Sheets("Macro Rules")
        .Range("B21").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[+1]"
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If your code stops, you probably misspelled the sheet name.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution to your problem, only a list of things to check:

1. The incorrect workbook is active
2. The tabname is miss-spelled
3. The is a protection / hidden issue